# Запятая перед КАК?

Tags: пунктуация

В правилах четко написано, что запятая перед КАК не ставится: если идет отрицание "НЕ КАК" или перед КАК стоят частицы СОВСЕМ, СОВЕРШЕННО и т.п.

Примеры:

В этот раз все прошло хорошо ,  не как в прошлый раз.

В этот раз все прошло плохо , совсем не как в прошлый раз.

В этот раз  все прошло чуть-чуть по-другому, не совсем как в прошлый раз.

Здесь ведь нужны запятые или нет?

Answer (score 3):

Нужны, но не из-за этого правила. Здесь просто однородные члены.
Сравните: *Это был синий шарик, не красный.*

Answer (score 3):

Оборот в данном случае является вторым обстоятельством и поэтому не обособляется. Однородных отношений здесь нет, оборот  имеет присоединительный характер.

Сравнить: В этот раз все прошло не как в прошлый раз. В этот раз все прошло хорошо , не как в прошлый раз.

Причина очевидная: мы просто не можем поставить рядом обычное обстоятельство и СОЮЗНЫЙ оборот, не разделив их запятой.

Но: Всё прошло хорошо в прошлый раз (два неоднородных обстоятельства стоят рядом)

Answer (score 2):

***Запятые в данных предложениях поставлены правильно, ибо перед нами неполные придаточные сравнительные, которые часто путают со сравнительными оборотами.***

Придаточные сравнительные часто бывают неполными предложениями.

Широкие тени ходят по равнине, как облака по небу (Чехов) – опущено сказуемое ходят.

Следует отличать неполное придаточное предложение от сравнительного оборота. В сравнительном придаточном допускается пропуск сказуемого – оно уже названо в главном предложении (см. пример выше). Так как в придаточном предложении с опущенным сказуемым остаются подлежащее и второстепенные члены, грамматически зависящие от сказуемого (обстоятельство, дополнение), то сказуемое может быть без труда восстановлено.

Ср.: Существование его заключено в эту тесную программу, как яйцо в скорлупу (Чехов). – Существование его заключено в эту тесную программу, как яйцо заключено в скорлупу.

Если в сравнительной конструкции нет членов предложения, зависящих от сказуемого, то она превращается в сравнительный оборот.[Здесь](http://www.licey.net/russian/syntax/r2_2_3_1)